# Is it advisable to use Active Resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, net-http, activeresource

I get data from an API, and I use Net::HTTP to do requests from/to the API. I basically just receive data from Net::HTTP then store it in an instance variable inside a controller then display information in html.

But my issue is that, my code doesn't have structure like Models(I perform everything from one model :( ), or Model Associations, the application is getting bigger, with no structure, it's super hard to debug. And boring.

In addition, the application is getting slower, my initial thought is that Net::HTTP takes time to perform some tasks that would be faster in a library like ActiveRecord/ActiveResource.

I want to start using **Active Resource**, it seems like a good library but I'm unsure about it, old videos say it's hard to debug and it's a no go area for big rails applications.

My question is, should I go ahead and build this application with Active Resource? Or if there are any suggestions to help me bring a structure to the application and make it faster, it would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: ActiveResource is an OO wrapper around http client. It cannot possibly make anything faster.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that means probably there's something that I'm doing that makes the application slow, or the API is slow